# Swap function for user-defined class never instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation, swap

The following is a reduced example of something I'm stumbling across with a larger class I'm creating and attempting to make Swappable by providing my own non-member friend swap function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
  friend void swap(Wrapper& a, Wrapper& b);

public:
  Wrapper(T t) : value_(t) {}
  const T& operator*() const { return value_; }

private:
  T value_;
};

template<typename T>
void swap(Wrapper<T>& a, Wrapper<T>& b) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(a.value_, b.value_);
}

int main() {
  Wrapper<int> w1{5}, w2{10};
  std::cout << *w1 << " " << *w2 << std::endl;
  swap(w1, w2);
  std::cout << *w1 << " " << *w2 << std::endl;
}
```

Attempting to compile this small test program results in the following linker error from clang (Apple LLVM version 7.0.2, clang-700.1.81 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3):

```
[~/Development/c++_test][16:30:57]$ clang++ --std=c++11 -o SwapTest SwapTest.cc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "swap(Wrapper<int>&, Wrapper<int>&)", referenced from:
      _main in SwapTest-a978ea.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is the template swap function for my Wrapper class that I've defined not instantiated appropriately despite my use of it in main()?

Comment: You need to declare `swap` as a template before declaring it as a friend function (`template <typename T> void swap(Wrapper<T>&, Wrapper<T>&`). Of course this also means declaring `Wrapper` before *that* declaration since you have them as argument types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
friend void swap(Wrapper& a, Wrapper& b);
```

declares a non-template function `swap` that happens to take `Wrapper<T>&` arguments.  This doesn't match with your template function `swap<T>`.

One simple fix is to declare the friend as the template function.

```
template <typename U>
friend void swap(Wrapper<U>&a, Wrapper<U>& b);
```

The drawback there is you've friended a little more than you wanted: every `swap` instantiation is a friend of every `Wrapper<T>`, not just the correct `Wrapper<T>` class.

A more correct way involves declaring the template function before the class:

```
template <class T> class Wrapper;
template <class T>
void swap(Wrapper<T>&, Wrapper<T>&);

template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
    friend void swap<>(Wrapper&, Wrapper&);
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, especially the "quick" fix and then the more correct fix that avoids friending more than necessary. Obviously this touched on details of templates that I'm still shaky with; I was mistakenly thinking that the friend function swap would be a template declaration as well since it was inside the template class, but it now makes sense that it isn't.

Comment: or define the non-template friend in the class definition and avoid polluting the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your friend declaration to be a template:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
  template<typename U>
  friend void swap(Wrapper<U>& a, Wrapper<U>& b);
  ...
```

gcc outputs a warning about this when trying to compile your code